# Clojure + Compojure + Maven application doesn't work in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, clojure, maven, war, compojure

I'm working on a simple web application written in Clojure, using the Compojure web application framework and Maven.

This is a simplified version of my servlet:

```
(ns core
  (:use compojure.core ring.util.servlet)
  (:require [compojure.route :as route])
  (:gen-class :extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet))

(defroutes main-routes
  (GET "/" _ {:status 302 :headers {"Location" "/about"}})
  (GET "/about" [] "This is the about page")
  (route/not-found "File not found."))

(defservice main-routes)
```

This works fine using Maven's Jetty goal like this:

```
mvn jetty:run
```

However, when I build a WAR from this and deploy it on a Tomcat, I always see my 404 page, i.e. "File not found.". Can you tell me why this happens?

I build the WAR as follows:

```
mvn package
```

I noticed a warning in Tomcat about duplicate servlet-api.jar, and Maven does indeed put it into WEB-INF/lib. I removed servlet-api.jar from the WAR and still get the same problem, but does this mean that something is wrong with my whole WAR packaging process?

Can this perhaps be an issue with the different URL path? When I start a local Jetty, the URL is as follows:

http://localhost:8080/home

But if I launch it on a Tomcat, it is like this:

http://localhost:8080/myapp/home

So is the "/myapp" perhaps part of the route? How would I tackle that problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look to [following example](https://github.com/alexott/clojure-examples/tree/master/compojure-simple) - it run both in tomcat & jetty. If you use **mvn jetty:run**, then you need also to specify prefix that will be used (you can see this in [pom.xml](https://github.com/alexott/clojure-examples/blob/master/compojure-simple/cpj-war/pom.xml) for war target)

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out thanks to your project. The trick is to 1. Set a context path for jetty as you explained and 2. to set the name of the generated war to "myapp", so it won't be "myapp-1.0.0-SNAPHOT". Any idea about why servlet-api.jar is included for me?

Answer (score 0):

Freely quoted from http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo:

> If you are using the "war" method to deploy your application:
>
> - delete the ROOT directory
> - name your war file "ROOT.war" (capitals mandatory)
> - drop the ROOT.war file directly in the /webapps directory.
>   Tomcat will automatically deploy it.

Comment: I don't think that's such a good idea: This would mean that only one application like mine can be installed on the server.